# WPF MVVM combine two collections in one view model

Tags: c#, mvvm, wpf-controls

I'm struggling with something and hope somebody can help with a tip on how to accomplish this:

I wrote a UserControl that looks like a File Explorer with on the left side a TreeView with diskdrives and folders (each item has a checkbox) and as soon as a TreeViewItem on the left side is selected, the right side should display the contents of that directory in a ListView, also with a checkbox for each file.

The TreeView is bound in a ViewModel and has many children and subchildren. This works well. The right side however, should only be 1 level of children and no subchildren.

I get the "IsSelected" event within the ViewModel, but of course I then have a reference to the current selected TreeViewItem on the left side, which is totally unrelated to the main level ListView on the right side, which I need to fill with data at that point. How can I reach the main level ListView on the right side, is there any way to create a global lvMain or something that I can access from within the ViewModel or am I appoaching all of this the wrong way and do I need 2 ViewModels instead? Any tips are welcome!

Edit: Here is an image of the desired result, it is the non MVVM version of it, which I am now converting to a control that uses a viewmodel in order to add extra functionality:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI6Bm.jpg)

Some XAML code snippets:

```
<TreeView Name="myTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding tvChildren}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"></TreeView>
...
<ListView x:Name="myListView" FontWeight="Normal" ItemsSource="{Binding lvChildren}" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

UserObject code snippets:

```
public FileExplorer()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        // Initially fill TreeView (left side of FileExplorer) with local drives:
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        ViewModel dummyNode = null;
        int i = 0;

        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            if (drive.DriveType != DriveType.CDRom)
            {
                ViewModel node = new ViewModel();
                tvMainNode.tvChildren.Add(node);
                node.Text = drive.Name;
                node.FullDir = drive.Name;
                node._parent = tvMainNode;

                // Add a blanc child so the toggle buttons are generated:
                tvMainNode.tvChildren[i].tvChildren.Add(dummyNode);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { return; }
    DataContext = this;
}
```

ViewModel code snippet:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<ViewModel> _tvChildren = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
private readonly ObservableCollection<ViewModel> _lvChildren = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
void SetIsSelected(bool value)
{
    if (value == _isSelected) { return; }
    _isSelected = value;

// This is obviously not working:
    ViewModel test = new ViewModel();
    this.lvChildren.Clear();
    test.Naam = "bla";
    this.lvChildren.Add(test);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to visualize your problem without you sharing your related codes on the issue. Also you can post an image of the user control you're trying to describe so we can all see easily.

Comment: Question title is misleading: folder view doesn't contains files. You can simply process selection changes of TreeView (folders) to generate content for right panel (showing files). Use cache for better performance (when returning to already visited folder).

Comment: I added an image and some code samples. Yes I want to process selection changes, but the problem is that I have no handle to the right side ListView at the point where I receive the event.

Comment: You're not using proper MVVM - use a MainViewModel and a DriveViewModel. And then your problem can probably be solved by binding to the SelectedItem property. But binding a TreeView is a little tricky, search on that topic.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I'm going to look into this, however I'm not sure if I understand what you mean with "DriveViewModel" and "binding a TreeView is tricky". Also I'm not sure what the MainViewModel's task should be.

Comment: With MVVM you shouldn't use `DataContext = this;`. Use a MainViewModel instead.

Comment: Thanks Henk, it took me a long time but I'm starting to finally understand more about MVVM (I'm still learning about this topic). I see I was doing things the wrong way, thanks for pointing it out. However now a new question raised, but I'll put it in a new thread...